# Escaping characters for logical bit shift in batch file

Tags: batch-file, escaping

I want to perform logical shift for 26000 in batch file. The result should be 101 but instead it creates a file named 8.

```
@echo off
set "newvalue=26000"
set /a test=%newvalue% ^>> 8
echo %test%
```

Caret is supposed to escape the signs but in this particular case it won't work

Comment: Well, you have to escape *each character*, like `^>^>`; anyway, let me recommend quotation for the sake of legibility…

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Found it.
You can overcome this by putting it in quotation marks.

```
set /a "test=%newvalue% >> 8"
```